# Does a US visa refusal need to be mentioned in a Schengen visa application?

Tags: schengen-visas

The link [here](http://www.pakistan.diplo.de/Vertretung/pakistan/en/06Legal/1__visa__shortterm/1__Business__Visa__Seite.html) mentions the following:

> 8. If you have been refused a visa by an Embassy or High Commission, written explanation about reason for trip and refusal letter.

If the visa refusal was from a country other than the Schengen states (for example, the US), does the above apply to that refusal too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you apply for visa from an embassy or high commission and get a refusal? If so, yes you will have to mention it.

The question does not ask if you were refused by an embassy of a Schengen country, it asks if you were ever refused a visa anywhere. This would include the USA.

Comment: AFAIK USA visas are sometimes issued by consulates and not Embassies.

Comment: I would still be inclined to mention such a refusal.